# Pandas - Searching Column of Data Frame from List Efficiently

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, processing-efficiency

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to search a data frame in Pandas with a list (dataframe) of other values without using brute force methods.  Is there a way to vectorize it?  I know I can for loop each element of the list (or dataframe) and extract the data using the loc method, but was hoping for something faster.  I have a data frame with 1 million rows and I need to search within it to extract the index of 600,000 rows.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'WholeList': np.round(1000000*(np.random.rand(1000000)),0)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ThingsToFind': np.arange(50000)+50000})
df.loc[1:10,:]
#Edited, now that I think about it, the 'arange' method would have been better to populate the arrays.
```

I want the most efficient way to get the index of df2 in df, where it exists in df.

Thanks!

Comment: So, the output would be of length `1 million`?

Comment: Also, what to output if there's isn't a match of `df2` in `df`?

Comment: Did you try to use the isin() DataFrame method?

Comment: Either length would be ok now that I think about it.

Comment: @Andrew L I've mainly tried brute forcing through the loc method, but I assumed this is the most time intensive way to do it.

Comment: @wwii Thanks for the tip.  I see it in a solution below as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach with [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) as it seems the second dataframe has its elements sorted and unique -

```
def find_index(a,b, invalid_specifier = -1):
    idx = np.searchsorted(b,a)
    idx[idx==b.size] = 0
    idx[b[idx] != a] = invalid_specifier
    return idx

def process_dfs(df, df2):
    a = df.WholeList.values.ravel()
    b = df2.ThingsToFind.values.ravel()
    return find_index(a,b, invalid_specifier=-1)
```

Sample run on arrays -

```
In [200]: a
Out[200]: array([ 3,  5,  8,  4,  3,  2,  5,  2, 12,  6,  3,  7])

In [201]: b
Out[201]: array([2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [202]: find_index(a,b, invalid_specifier=-1)
Out[202]: array([ 1,  2,  5, -1,  1,  0,  2,  0, -1,  3,  1,  4])
```

Sample run on dataframes -

```
In [188]: df
Out[188]: 
    WholeList
0           3
1           5
2           8
3           4
4           3
5           2
6           5
7           2
8          12
9           6
10          3
11          7

In [189]: df2
Out[189]: 
   ThingsToFind
0             2
1             3
2             5
3             6
4             7
5             8
6             9

In [190]: process_dfs(df, df2)
Out[190]: array([ 1,  2,  5, -1,  1,  0,  2,  0, -1,  3,  1,  4])
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is an interesting approach.

Comment: This worked beautifully.  isin() didn't give me what I wanted, but this was brilliant.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pandas dataframes have an `isin()` method that works really well:

```
df[df.WholeList.isin(df2.ThingsToFind)]
```

It seems reasonably performant on my MBP:

```
CPU times: user 3 µs, sys: 5 µs, total: 8 µs
Wall time: 11 µs
```

Comment: But, we need to get the indexes of `df2` corresponding to the matches, right?

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean. There's no explicit index in df2. You looking for the row number index? um, that's simply  `df[df.WholeList.isin(df2.ThingsToFind)].index`

Comment: @Divaker  I would say that as long as I can easily have it where WholeList(index our function would provide)=ThingsToFind, then I'd be happy.  I'm thinking of a MATLAB command that I love and trying to implement it in Python.  Sorry if this is a newbie question, but I'm only in month 2 of the language.

Comment: I'll give isin a try.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @JDLong - IMO Pandas is pretty fast:

```
In [49]: %timeit df[df.WholeList.isin(df2.ThingsToFind)]
1 loop, best of 3: 819 ms per loop

In [50]: %timeit df.loc[df.WholeList.isin(df2.ThingsToFind)]
1 loop, best of 3: 814 ms per loop

In [51]: %timeit df.query("WholeList in @df2.ThingsToFind")
1 loop, best of 3: 837 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks.  I assumed there were other approaches than the brute force + loc method.  I'll give this a try.